# How set text field location in Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout

How set text field location in Java GUI?

I tried this:

```
public Apletas() 
{
    inputLine.setLocation(null);
    inputLine.setLocation(80, 80);
    add(inputLine);
}
```

But not working.

Comment: Do you have a layout manager applied to the Apletas class, whatever it is? Please post a full source code.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  "How set textField location in Java applet?"  The same way you would do it in a Java `JFrame` (`JWindow`, `JDialog`, `JInternalFrame` etc.) see my answer re how to do that.

Comment: BTW - 1) The use of `textField` does not help us to know whether it is a `java.awt.TextField` or `javax.swing.JTextField`.  In this millennium, stick to Swing.  2) I edited the question to remove the applet references and add GUI & layout tags.

Answer (score 1):

First, set the layout of your applet to `null`:

```
  ...
  public void init()
  {
    setLayout(null);
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignore `setLocation()`/`setBounds()` & **most especially** `setLayout(null)`.  Abandon all hope (& the last remnants of sanity), ye' who enter there.

Set locations of components using layout managers.

For sizing of components, it is usually sufficient to provide the appropriate arguments in the constructor (e.g. `new JTextArea(rows, columns)`), or in some cases, using layout constraints (e.g `BorderLayout.CENTER`).

For spacing between components, look into both the `javax.swing.border` package and arguments to the constructor of layout managers, or in some cases, layout constraints (e.g `GridBagLayout` & `GridBagConstraints`).

**Example:**

```
//<applet code='Apletas' width='600' height='400'></applet>
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Apletas extends JApplet {

    private JTextField inputLine;

    public Apletas()
    {
        inputLine = new JTextField(20);

        JPanel mainGui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(20,20));
        mainGui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(80,80,80,80));

        mainGui.add(inputLine, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        mainGui.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(20,10)), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.expandRow(2);
        mainGui.add(new JScrollPane(tree), BorderLayout.WEST);

        setContentPane(mainGui);
        validate();
    }
}
```

**To compile & run**

```
prompt> javac Apletas.java
prompt> appletviewer Apletas.java
```

**See also**

[Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) & [How to Use Borders](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) in the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would `.setLocation(null)` on a text field and then set it again.

Is inputLine declared elsewhere (in which case post the full code here please) or are you missing a line like

```
TextField inputLine = new TextField("Hello world");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to null the default layout as by using the code

```
setLayout(null);
```

and then can use the setBounds method to locate your swings
it goes like this

```
JTextField jt = new JTextField();
jt.setBounds(x,y,width,height);
```